# variable value from http request / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, request

I am doing a http request in js but I cannot access the data I get from outside.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  search=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  search=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
search.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (search.readyState==4 && search.status==200)
    {
        nr = search.responseText;
        alert(nr.length); // here i get the actual length
    }
  }
search.open("GET","clienti.php",true);
search.send();
alert(nr);  // here the value is undefined
```

I tried to declare variable globally but still doesnt work. Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you declared 'nr' above?

Comment: ajax is async, `nr = search.responseText;` is called after `alert(nr);`

Comment: jQuery && Microsoft.XMLHTTP ???

Answer (score 0):

```
var nr;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  search=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
  search=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
search.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (search.readyState==4 && search.status==200)
  {
    nr = search.responseText;         
    alert(nr.length); // here i get the actual length
  }
}
search.open("GET","clienti.php",true);
search.send();
alert(nr);
```

With your code `nr` is private to `onreadystatechange` block.

Comment: I found out that the last alert is running before the request in completed, thats why i get value undefined :). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you have scope problem define nr as global variable and than try

```
 var nr=0;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      search=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {
      search=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    search.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (search.readyState==4 && search.status==200)
        {
            nr = search.responseText;
            alert(nr.length); // here i get the actual length
        }
      }
    search.open("GET","clienti.php",true);
    search.send();
    alert(nr);  /
```